# afterSave - конкретное поле

Tags: php, yii2

Вопрос по yii2 framework.

Как узнать в afterSave, поменялось ли значение поля?

Работаю с нотификейшинами выдавать сообщение, когда конкретное поле изменилось.

Вот такой схемой пользуюсь, при insert все норм, узнаю нужные данные

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        if ($insert) {
                // Да это новая запись (insert)
        } else {
                // Нет, старая (update)
        }
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```

Но как быть при update? У меня, к примеру есть поле `status - 0/1`. Если значение поменялось, мне нужно узнать id записи, и записать в другую таблицу. Как это сделать, может кто-то стыкался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getOldAttribute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#getOldAttribute()-detail) - вернет предыдущее значение

[getOldAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#getOldAttributes()-detail) - вернет все атрибуты и их значения до изминений

```
if ($insert) {
        // Да это новая запись (insert)
} else {
    if($this->status != $this->getOldAttribute('status')){
        //...$this->id
    }
}
```

Есть еще метод [isAttributeChanged()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#isAttributeChanged()-detail), принцип у него тот же, как и описано выше

```
if ($insert) {
        // Да это новая запись (insert)
} else {
    if($this->isAttributeChanged('status')){
        //...$this->id
    }
}
```

Comment: `print_r($this->status);` и 
`print_r($this->getOldAttribute('status'));` Выдают одинаковые значения

Comment: Судя по комиту - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/f4395206b7192a74ce50d9398805e552b1c60931, оно должно работать верно, может где в другом месте ошибка, что говорит `beforeSave` на то же выражение?

Comment: Да уже, странно. в `beforeSave` работает правильно.

Comment: В принципе, подойдет и в `beforeSave`, id же не меняется, а мене по сути только id нужно. Спасибо